# Dojo: BorderContainer - Toggle the left sidebar pane width to 0

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.layout

I have a BorderContainer {design: "sidebar"} with a AccordionContainer {region: "left"} in the left pane. The Splitter is enabled to allow dragging the AccordionContainer 'closed', but with the splitter still available at the left edge to drag it back 'open'.

How can I toggle it from the current width to 0px with code?
- How do I get the current width?
- How do I set the width and redraw if necessary?

I do not want to removeChild/Addchild as this removes the splitter.

[ Edit: Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/6aNrp/274/ ]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think You want [dojo.marginBox](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/marginBox.html).

Comment: While that does get and set the width - using 'AccordionContainer.domNode', I can't get the BorderContainer to resize the center pane to the available width - 'BorderContainer.resize()' does nothing.

Comment: I got it to work (http://jsfiddle.net/6aNrp/274/). Not sure what I was doing wrong before. Thanks

Comment: Just make sure to test it in different browsers. I know that in dojo 1.6 marginBox gives different results(dimesoins, including borders in IE and don't in FF or vice versa(can't remember)).